# How can i get my own wall posts using the Facebook c# API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am being incredible dim, but i cannot seem to get my head around or find any examples of using the Facebook c# API to get a list of wall posts.  Now initially, for testing i just want to get my own, this will be replaced with the clients wall posts, but in essence the procedure will be the same.  It is simply to show the wall posts in a styled format on my clients new website.

I need some help/guidance with

- Becuase this is data owned by the person (i.e. me and my client) do i still need to get an authentication token or can i generate one for this purpose (i already have an app token/secret)
- How can i grab the posts, i tried looking at the examples but even though i really see the benefit of the dynamic approach, especially with a beast like Facebook, without the intellisence i am like a beached whale, flapping around but going nowhere.

Does anyone know how to do this, or have any good examples anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter what you do, you need users permission, for that, you need to create a Facebook App first.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create one.

If you are using it only in a website, just fillup the website URL with your `http://localhost:12345` save it, grab the secret and api key and ad to your `web.config` file in the Facebook C# SDK area.

Now that you can get information on your page, you need to ask permission to the user to request the wall posts, you will find all [request permissions in facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

That goes on either the javascript if you want to use the Facebook javascript API (fastest) or as an attribute in the Action that needs that permission.

You might find the [Video from the author of this SDK](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/OPN06) that he gave in MIX this year, to be a nice tool to start you up really nice.

Comment: Hi balexandre, thanks for the reply and sorry for the late comment, i have app set up, but i am using sitefnity and cant get the latest version of the c# api to work so will have to go down the route of using the javascript api i think.

Answer (score 0):

heyy rob,
to get the user's wall post, you have to make use of facebook graph API...check out here..
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
this document is pretty cool...
you can generate API call
for example.... to get the wall post..
JsonObject fbJsonFeedObj = (JsonObject)fb.Get(" https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=from,message,name,picture&access_token=" + _accessToken);
this can be useful, it will return the result in json object.
and be sure that you have read_stream permission!

Answer (score 0):

this is how to view your facebook post using c# and asp.net:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient("your token here");
    var query = string.Format(@"SELECT status_id,message,time,source,uid,place_id
                                FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM status WHERE uid = 'Your FB ID here') ORDER BY time DESC");

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.q = query;
    dynamic results = fb.Get("/fql", parameters);

    List<MyPost> q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyPost>>(results.data.ToString());

    GridView2.DataSource = q;
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
 public class MyPost
{
    public long status_id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public long uid { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: i you are using visual studio just add references and search for facebook.dll - @ArjendeMooij